# Why canvas not scrolling with scrollbar and auto resizing when adding widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When i put widgets inside my canvas, the widgets bypass the canvas size. But when I scroll, the canvas won't move.
On top of that, the canvas auto re-sizes when I add more widgets. I thought the canvas isn't supposed to re-size because I already added a scroll bar?

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import mysql.connector

class CanvasScroll:

    def on_resize(self,event):
        self.canvas.config(width = 1185, height = 530)

    def add_crew(self):
        crewFrame = CrewFrame()


    def callback_list(self):
        index = self.notebook.index(self.notebook.select()) + 1
        self.tmpframe = Try2(self.contentframe, index)


    def __init__(self, master):
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, width = 1185, height = 530, scrollregion = (0, 0, 1216, 700), bg = 'white', confine = True)
        self.canvas.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'news')

        self.xscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(master, orient = HORIZONTAL, command = self.canvas.xview)
        self.xscroll.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = 'we')

        self.yscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(master, orient = VERTICAL, command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.yscroll.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = 'ns')

        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand = self.xscroll.set, yscrollcommand = self.yscroll.set)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)


        self.option = ttk.Frame(master, height = 150, width = 1206)
        self.option.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'we', columnspan = 5)

        self.addicon = PhotoImage(file = 'C:\\Users\\rain\\Desktop\\Fyosh!\\logo\\add.gif').subsample(2,2)
        self.btnAdd = ttk.Button(self.option, image = self.addicon, text = 'Add Crew', compound = TOP, command = self.add_crew)
        self.btnAdd.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 50, pady = 5)

        self.updateicon = PhotoImage(file = 'C:\\Users\\rain\\Desktop\\Fyosh!\\logo\\update.gif').subsample(2,2)
        self.btnUpdate = ttk.Button(self.option, image = self.updateicon, text = 'Update Crew', compound = TOP)
        self.btnUpdate.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 50)

        self.deleteicon = PhotoImage(file = 'C:\\Users\\rain\\Desktop\\Fyosh!\\logo\\delete.gif').subsample(2,2)
        self.btnDelete = ttk.Button(self.option, image = self.deleteicon, text = 'Delete Crew', compound = TOP)
        self.btnDelete.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 50)

        self.reloadicon = PhotoImage(file = 'C:\\Users\\rain\\Desktop\\Fyosh!\\logo\\Refresh.png').subsample(7,7)
        self.reloadbtn = ttk.Button(self.option, image = self.reloadicon, command = self.callback_list, text = 'Load List', compound = TOP)
        self.reloadbtn.grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx = 50)

        self.tabframe = ttk.Frame(master, height = 20)
        self.tabframe.grid(row = 1, sticky = 'we')

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.tabframe)
        self.notebook.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'we')

        db = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = '', host = 'localhost', database = 'fat2x_payroll')
        cursor = db.cursor()

        ships = ("SELECT * from tbl_shiplist")

        try:
            cursor.execute(ships)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            self.tab = {}
            for row in result:
                self.tab[row[0]] = {
                    "shipname": ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
                    }
                self.notebook.add(self.tab[row[0]]["shipname"], text = row[1])
                db.close()

        except:
            messagebox.showinfo("alert", "ship list error")

        self.canvas.label = ttk.Label(self.canvas, text = "hahahahahha").grid(column = 0)
        self.canvas.label1 = ttk.Label(self.canvas, text = "hahahahahha").grid(column = 1)
        self.canvas.label2 = ttk.Label(self.canvas, text = "hahahahahha").grid(column = 2)
        self.canvas.label3 = ttk.Label(self.canvas, text = "hahahahahha").grid(column = 3)
        self.canvas.label4 = ttk.Label(self.canvas, text = "hahahahahha").grid(column = 4)
        self.canvas.label5 = ttk.Label(self.canvas, text = "hahahahahha").grid(column = 5)
        self.canvas.label6 = ttk.Label(self.canvas, text = "hahahahahha").grid(column = 6)
        self.canvas.label7 = ttk.Label(self.canvas, text = "hahahahahha").grid(column = 7)
        self.canvas.label8 = ttk.Label(self.canvas, text = "hahahahahha").grid(column = 8)

def start():
    master = Tk()
    master.geometry("1206x690+10+10")
    master.resizable(0,0)
    master.title("Crew Panel")
    canvasScroll = CanvasScroll(master)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas can only scroll objects that are embedded on the canvas. In the case of widgets, that means that you've called the [create_window](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method) method of the canvas for the widgets you want to be affected by the scrollbar.

If you want to use `grid` to organize widgets, and you want those widgets to be in a scrollable container, the usual method is to put those widgets inside a frame, and then add the frame to the canvas with create_window. You can see an example of this technique in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/7432

As for the auto-resize, this behavior is completely unrelated to using a scrollbar. If you use `grid` or `pack` on a widget, the parent will always resize unless you've turned geometry propagation off. It doesn't matter if it's a Canvas or a Frame or a Toplevel, or any other class of widget.